# Lazy mathematician: what are the real lengths in an Ideal Lambert quadrilateral?

Tags: functions, hyperbolic-geometry

At the moment it is to hot for real mathematics but I wanted to have a function that relates the lengths of the real sides of an Ideal Lambert quadrilateral

An **Ideal Lambert quadrilateral** (my term, **not** an official name) is a Lambert Quadrilateral ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_quadrilateral ) where the not right angled vertex is an ideal point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_point so the fourth angle is zero.

and the question is how do the lengths of the sides that ***not** meet at the ideal vertex relate to eachother.

the proper way to get this function is complicated and tedious and so so I thought is there no shortcut? (and it is hot now)

What do we know about this function and which functions are this way?

If we call this relation $f(x)$ we have the following facts:

- we only need to concider values of $ x \gt 0  $
- $ \forall x\gt 0   : f(x) \ge 0 $
- $ \forall x \gt 0  : f(f(x)) = x $
- $ \forall x \gt 0, y  : x \le y \to f(y) \le  f(x) $

and the only function I know where all these apply is the function

$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{x} $$

Is this enough to conclude that $f(x) = g(x) $ or are there other functions where these relations hold and i do need to do my tedious mathematics?

Comment: I think, any proportion $a:b$ can be realized with an ideal point.

Comment: added the relationship between the two lengths. What we get directly from my diagram is $ \tanh^2 s + \tanh^2 t = 1, $ so $\tanh s = \operatorname{sech} t$ and $ \operatorname{sech} s = \tanh t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see in the diagram of the upper half plane in $\mathbb C,$ the ratio (or difference) of lengths of the two finite sides varies continuously with the real parameter I am calling $A,$ with $A > 0.$ The three (finite) vertices are at
$$ i, \; \; \; \; A + i \sqrt {1 + A^2},  \; \; \; \; \frac{-1}{A} +  \frac{i}{A} \sqrt {1 + A^2}.  $$

Oh, for real $E$ and real $F > 0,$ the following is a geodesic parametrized by arc length $t:$
$$ E + F \tanh t + i F \operatorname{sech} t.   $$
This is one way to find out the lengths of the two finite Lambert segments in the diagram.

ADDED: if we call $s > 0, t > 0$ the lengths of the two finite edges, the requested relationship is not quite reciprocals, instead
$$  e^s = \frac{e^t + 1}{e^t - 1} $$
and
$$  e^t = \frac{e^s + 1}{e^s - 1} $$
Note that the Möbius transformation
$$ f(z) = \frac{z+1}{z-1} $$
is its own inverse.

Since, for some $0 \leq u < 1,$ we have bounds
$$ u - \frac{u^2}{2} \leq \log (1+u) \leq u,  $$
the relationship $$s = \log \left(1 + \frac{2}{e^t - 1} \right) $$
says that, as $t \rightarrow +\infty,$ that
$$ s \approx \frac{2}{e^t}. $$

[image]

Here is a graph of $  s = \log \left( \frac{e^t + 1}{e^t - 1} \right) $

[image]